# Extra Edit screens for the same resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have a resource "Providers" that has a settings screen.  I want to break that out into several screens for usability / design reasons. How should I manage that in my controllers to maintain good rails practice?

Is it acceptable to simply create new member actions for the controller (two per screen for the edit / update pairing) or is there a better / more accepted method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just continue to have 1 action/route and add logic inside of it to decide which partial to render.  Something like this:

```
def edit
  @provider = Provider.find(params[:id])
  if params[:form][:basic_info]
    render 'basic_info'
  if params[:form][:additional_info]
    render 'additional_info'
end
```

I would stray away from multiple edit/updates because in my experience I have only ever seen it as a hinderance to DRY.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer with the other steps for completeness, hope u don't mind.  The down side of this is its slightly more complex & the urls are not awesome.  but it is good for my situation.  : )